# Define multiple bluetooth dongles in python-bluez (scan from specific device)

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez

I'm building a bluetooth application in Python, using python-bluez (under linux)

But my computer has 2 bluetooth adapters (one built in, one usb dongle)
How can I choose which one to scan from, because now it randomly picks one.

The code right now is pretty basic ;)

```
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
```

Comment: I don't think it's randomly choosing.  It will default to the first available device, likely hci0 unless you have something using that device already.  You can try using `hciconfig hci0 down` to disable hci0 so your pybluez code will then pick up hci1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you have to modify the python-bluez file itself.

Comment: Could you please add the needed modification to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
   #Automatic selection:
   nearby_devices = discover_devices(lookup_names=True, device_id=-1)
   #First adapter
   nearby_devices = discover_devices(lookup_names=True, device_id=0)
   #Secon adapter
   nearby_devices = discover_devices(lookup_names=True, device_id=1)
   #..etc
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64928696/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.